# Resolving Dependency Hell with Composer

Tags: composer-php

This is the scenario.

You have package A and package B in your composer.json (your app depends on this 2 packages).

Both package A and B depend on package C, but on different versions. Say A depend on C v2.1, and B depends on C v2.2.

And you get version conflicts.

Both A, B and C are third party packages.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Is it possible for either A or B to work with the same version of C? I know different versions are forced by those packages but you could probably define repositories for those three in your composer.json to overwrite the versions. I know it's a hack but it could let you going.

Comment: Yes it is. But I'm not sure you can do that. I'll try. but I know if you put in your composer.json `"C": "2.2"`, and A have `"C": "2.1"`, you will get errors.

Comment: Yes, but my idea is to define repositories for all three packages. So you change A and B to rely on "C": "2.2". As long as both can work with 2.2...

Comment: Ah, yes, that will probably fix it. You can post answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hack but will probably let you move forward.

You could overwrite repositories for "A", "B" and "C" packages and make that "A" and "B" rely on the same  version of "C" (actually, might be that it's enough to overwrite repositories for "A" and "B" only).

This should work as long as both "A" and "B" can work with the latest version of "C" (so probably a maintainer didn't update the package version). If it's the case I'd also consider sending a pull request to the project which has an older version of a dependency.

Comment: Why doesn't composer allow package A and package B to depend on different versions of the same package. NPM is able to do this: http://blog.timoxley.com/post/20772365842/node-js-npm-reducing-dependency-overheads They just need some sort of nested vendor structure!

Comment: Also are you able to give an example inside the composer.json on how to overwrite the repositories to resolve the dependency conflict?

Answer (score 0):

We are discussing it in this mailing list : http://news.php.net/php.internals/72594

"No-conflict" technique must be implemented in PHP , it's not a composer fault

Comment: I would argue that this is a conceptual problem of the separation of the dependency management and the lack of context when autoloading your libs.
Even if php would provide an easy way, to include the same library with different versions in the same request (for example the composer loader would export the version into separate namespaces), you would still have to somehow map the calls from your libs to the proper dependency version.

Comment: @Tyrael That seems like a minor problem; you can alias the root namespace of the package so that the FQNS includes the package version but  is referenced in the normal way. e.g. /Vendor/Package/1.0.0/ is aliased as /Vendor/Package/; though I think you would need to limit the version changes that are installed independently, with minor versions simply overwriting the existing.